# Remaining Panda Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 Panda Data Frames.

For example:

1. First Data Frame with `Student ID` and `Students Name` of 100 students.
2. Second Data Frame also with `Student ID` and `Students Name` of 20 students. These 20 students are also in the First Data Frame. I need the remaining 80 students in another Data Frame?

Which function can I use?

Is `pd.merge` able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify your first DF to 3 students, and second DF to 1 student.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 2, 3], "Name":["a", "b", "c"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[3], "Name":["c"]})

new_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

`pd.concat` will concatenate dataframes, and use `drop_duplicates(keep=False)` to remove duplicate values.